# Mumford's definition of an abelian variety's $Pic^0$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, line-bundles

I'm not sure whether this is a research-level question, but upon skimming through Mumford book of Abelian Varieties I noticed he gives this definition
$$
\begin{equation}
\label{eq}
\text{Pic}^0(A)=\{\mathcal{L}\in\text{Pic}(A)\text{ such that }t_a^*\mathcal{L}\simeq\mathcal{L}\text{ for all }a\in A\}
\end{equation}
$$
for an abelian variety $A$. I would really like to find a proof that these are exactly the line bundles algebraically equivalent to zero, which avoids all sorts of representability results. My attemps so far have yielded only meagre results.

1. Let $\mathcal{L}$ be as above, and $\mathcal{K}$ an ample line bundle. Then Mumford proves that for some $a\in A$ the sheaf $\mathcal{K}^{-1}\otimes t_a^*\mathcal{K}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{L}$, so the sheaf $m^*\mathcal{K}\otimes\mathcal{K}^{-1}$ is an algebraic deformation of $\mathcal{L}$ to $\mathcal{O}_A$.
2. And let us now consider a sheaf $\mathcal{C}$ on a curve $C\times A$ which deforms $\mathcal{L}$ to $\mathcal{O}_A$ (for convenience I also set $\mathcal{C}_{C\times0}=\mathcal{O}_C$).  The hope would be to show that *every* fibre of $\mathcal{C}$ is in Mumford's set, and this is where I've come short of ideas :/ An (infinitesimal) direction I explored was trying to show that $\mathcal{C}_a:=\mathcal{C}^{-1}\otimes (id\times t_a)^*\mathcal{C}$ has trivial fibres; this is true *a posteriori* and looks kind of cute, also because $\mathcal{C}_a$ has the nice property that, if I'm not mistaken,
   $$
   \mathcal{C}_{a+b}\simeq (\text{id}\times t_b)^*(\mathcal{C}_a)
   $$
   but I haven't managed any progress with it.

I would be equally satisfied of a heuristic argument which refutes the existence of such an elementary proof, actually.

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  The operation of $A$ on first-order deformations $\mathcal{L}$ of $\mathcal{O}_A$ sending $\mathcal{L}$ to $\mathcal{L}^\vee\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_A} t_a^*\mathcal{L}$ induces a morphism from $A$ to $\textbf{GL}(H^1(A,\mathcal{O}_A))$.  The domain is proper, and the target is affine, therefore the morphism is constant.  The same argument applies for higher-order deformations as well.  Thus, your sheaf $\mathcal{C}_a$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_{C\times A}$ to all infinitesimal orders near $\mathcal{O}_A$.  Now use the theorem on formal functions.

Comment: . . . Correction: replace $\textbf{GL}$ by $\text{Hom}$.

Comment: Mm I'm not sure I understood everything that's implied in your answer, may I ask some further questions, to steer my doubts away? For one, what kind of space classifies higher-order deformations? Does it represent some functor, so as to guarantee the map from $A$ is a morphism? And secondly I tried writing down the argument with the formal function theorem: it implies that the pushforward of $\mathcal{C}_a$ onto C is locally free, and thus has a global nowhere-vanishing section on an open set $U\times A$. But the set where it has trivial fibres is closed so its fibres must all be free. Thanks!